# Deleting files which have been used in a C# LibraryStack in a Scatterview

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, pixelsense, scatterview

I'm new to C#/WPF/Surface programming.

I'm using a `LibraryStack` in a `ScatterViewItem` in a `ScatterView`:

```
<Grid Name="DataGrid" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LibraryItemTemplate">
            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Styles to ensure each library control uses the above defined templates -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:LibraryStack}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LibraryItemTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:LibraryBar}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LibraryItemTemplate}"/>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <Image Source="{Binding XPath=@FullPath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <s:ScatterView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <s:ScatterViewItem  Name="ScatterViewItem1" Background="DarkGray"   MinWidth="800" MinHeight="800" 
                             Orientation="0.0" CanRotate="False">
            <s:LibraryStack Name="LibraryStack1" Background="Transparent" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="800" AllowDrop="True" >

            </s:LibraryStack>
        </s:ScatterViewItem>
    </s:ScatterView>
</Grid>
```

I fill the Library Stack by setting a `ObservableCollection` to the `ItemsSource` of the `LibraryStack`. The `ObservableCollection` consists of strings, which are file paths to images.

```
ObservableCollection<string> oc = new ObservableCollection<string>(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder));
LibraryStack1.ItemsSource = ocs;
```

Now I've got a `ScatterViewItem` with all images in it with drag and drop.

Then I want to clear all images from the `LibraryStack`/`ScatterViewItem` and delete all files/images in the folder:

```
oc=null;
LibraryStack1.ItemsSource = null;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);

foreach (String file in files)
{
  try
  {
    File.Delete(file);
  }
  catch (Exception f)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(f);
  }
}
```

The ScatterViewItem on screen is empty, but there is allways an exception thrown, by deleting the files (`File.Delete(file)`):

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'xyz' because it is being used by another another process. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.Delete(String path) ...

Deleting over `FileInfo` throws the same exception.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the file attributes like this before deleting them.

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: That's unlikely to help, it looks like a file lock issue not a file permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible explanations:-

1. Another process has a lock on the file (I find OneDrive often locks my code to sync it). Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what has a lock on the file(s)
2. You're inadvertently locking the files somewhere in your code and blocking yourself